# How to modify audio level of video according to replaygain info?

Tags: audio, video, replaygain

I have a bunch of music videos I have downloaded from youtube. I usually put them in a playlist in mpc (Media Player Classic). The problem is that the audio levels of the videos are quite different and I have to adjust the volume for each one.

If I hear them in foobar2000 (it's an audio player) there's no problem because it can apply the replaygain info wich I have added to the videos, but mpc hasn's this feature.

Mpc has a normalization option but it is dynamic and is not what I want.

An aceptable solution would be to recode the video with the audio levels corrected. But I want to move the audio level globally to the video, not dynamic normalization. And also I want to leave the video untouched. What tool can I use?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)? it supports *replaygain*

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. I think it works only for audio files